# Two column OL border-bottom of last LI in column 1 overflows to column 2. How to fix?

Tags: css, html-lists

I have an OL with column-count: 2;

The bottom border on the last LI in the first column at the "REAP" list item overflows into the second column, sitting above the "Federal Incentive Tax Credit" list item. How can I fix it so the border on the last LI in the first column stays in the first column and does not flow into the top of the second column?

The page:

http://lockwoodsolar.com/website-design/services.html

The CSS:

```
ol.options {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: #444;
    line-height: 1.5;
    column-count: 2;
    column-width: 40%;
}
li.choice {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(230,173,0);
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: doesn't happen here on Firefox Mac, so probably a browser thing

Comment: Happens in Chrome. I was able to fix it by adding a width and height property to the LI elements. The underlying css for the html frame was also fluidly responsive using vw and % for text and structure. I had to change the OL parent div to be a static px width and the LI text to be a static px size to stay the same when the browser width changes.

Comment: I am now only using static px sizes for text and widths until the viewport reaches 800 or 900 px width, then changing element attributes at a media query for mobile, with a single column count at mobile to alleviate any variances because the border-bottom still "skips ahead" to the next column at some viewport widths. Not as perfectly fluid as I would like, but still a good result with application to both monitors and devices.

Comment: I also had to change the wording for each line of text in each LI so as not to flow over into a second line, making each LI a static size in static px measure both width-wise and height-wise to maintain a steady measurement for the columns.